# Помогите с Jsoup

Tags: java, android

Сделал вот такой парсер к `xml` странице. Необходимо доставать картинку к каждой новости, но почему то не получается. 
Посмотрите что не так? Все работает, а картинка нет.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap bitmap;

    String imageUrl= "http://pozerov.net/music/rss.xml";
    ArrayList<String> xmlTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> xmlDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> xmlLink=new ArrayList<String>();

    public class BackgroundProcesses extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog =new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.satirlayout, xmlTitleList);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");

            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            xmlTitleList=getListFromXML("http://pozerov.net/music/rss.xml");
            xmlDescription=getDescriptionFromXml("http://pozerov.net/music/rss.xml");
            xmlLink=getLinkFromXml("http://pozerov.net/music/rss.xml");

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(imageUrl).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data
                Elements img = document.select("src");
                // Locate the src attribute
                String imgSrc = img.select("img").attr("src");

                // Download image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

            public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> xmlList) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, xmlList);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View row = convertView;

                if(row==null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.satirlayout, parent, false);
                }

                TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
                label.setText(xmlTitleList.get(position));

                TextView label1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);
                label1.setText(xmlDescription.get(position));

                ImageView image =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                return row;
            }}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        new BackgroundProcesses().execute();

        ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                    Uri link = Uri.parse(xmlLink.get(position));

                    final Intent openBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,link);

                    startActivity(openBrowser);

                }

            });
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getListFromXML(String string){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(string);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document= dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // item etiketine sahip elementleri NodeList olarak tutar
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int i=0; i< nodeList.getLength(); i++){//item etiketine sahip elemanların olduğu listeden
                //title etiketine sahip olanlar almak için döngü
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Element element = (Element) node;

                NodeList nodeListText = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element elementText = (Element) nodeListText.item(0);

                // her title ı arrayliste ekletiyoruz.
                list.add(elementText.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDescriptionFromXml(String string){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(string);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document= dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // item etiketine sahip elementleri NodeList olarak tutar
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int i=0; i< nodeList.getLength(); i++){//item etiketine sahip elemanların olduğu listeden
                //title etiketine sahip olanlar almak için döngü
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Element element = (Element) node;

                NodeList nodeListText = element.getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element elementText = (Element) nodeListText.item(0);

                // her title ı arrayliste ekletiyoruz.
                list.add(elementText.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLinkFromXml(String strng)  {

        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            URL url=new URL(strng);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder=dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document=dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeListCountry=document.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListCountry.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node=nodeListCountry.item(i);
                Element elementMain=(Element) node;

                NodeList nodeListText=elementMain.getElementsByTagName("link");
                Element elementText=(Element) nodeListText.item(0);

                list.add(elementText.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());


            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String mDescr = null;
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body>"+mDescr+"</body></html>");
```

Вы в `mDescr` записываете null, и вставляете егог в `html` `body`: `"<html><body>"+mDescr+"</body></html>"`
В итоге в строке всегда будет `"<html><body>null</body></html>"`

Comment: Исправил на String mDescr; Все ровно ничего не появляется.....Может в image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); надо что то другое обьявлять, а не bitmap???

Comment: @user3711927, похоже, ничего ваши исправления не изменили. Отредактируйте вопрос, и покажите исправленный код

Comment: Исправления внес....

Comment: @user3711927, вы все равно `mDescr` нигде не заполняете

Comment: Блин как же быть? Есть мысли?

Comment: @user3711927, достаньте из XML тег description, из него содержимое CDATA, и запишите в mDescr

Comment: Это как? Помогите плиз, неделю мучаюсь уже.....

Comment: @user3711927,  Это кодом. Что именно у вас вызывает затруднения? писать вместо вас ваш код, как ни странно, я не собираюсь.

Comment: Как достать содержимое CDATA из description..... вот в чем затруднения....а с кодом я и сам как нибудь разберусь...

Comment: Как это записать тут: Elements img = document.select("description[CDATA[img[src~=.(png|jpe?g|JPG|jpg|gif|GIF)]");  ????

Comment: Статью обновил.